# Ruby on Rails: what does the => symbol mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working my way through Head First Rails, and I keep seeing `=>`. It's in the routes:

`map.connect '/marmots/new', controller=>'marmots', :action=>'new'`

It's in rendering partials:

`render :partial=>"new_marmot"`

It's in options for links:

`<%= link_to 'Destroy', marmot, :confirm=>'Are you sure?', :method=>:delete %>`

Basically, `=>` seems to mean 'equals,' but if so, why not just use an equals sign? Is it more like 'send to?'

**How do you pronounce => and what do you understand it to mean?** I can get by without knowing this, but it bugs me.

Comment: Seeing this question 3 years later makes me laugh! I'm sure I had seen Ruby hashes before, but maybe I hadn't seen examples outside of Rails where you omit both the parentheses of a method call and the braces around a final hash argument, so it just looked like magic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your first function call is a shortcut for

```
map.connect('/marmots/new', {:controller=>'marmots', :action=>'new'})
```

where the {} are a Hash-literal. The second argument of the method connect of the object map is an object of class Hash with the two keys :controller and :action (both are literals of the class Symbol) whose corresponding values are the two strings 'marmots' and 'new'.

EDIT: I call it "arrow" or "maps to".

Comment: Is it safe to say that anytime I see the arrow, I'm actually creating a hash, even if the {} are omitted?

Comment: Yes for the parameters in method calls, no in general (if you catch an exception with rescue, the operator "=>" is also used).

Answer (score 22):

I've heard it commonly referred to as a "hash rocket".  It is the assignment operator used with hashes in ruby.  So if you have a hash and want to assign a value to a key (typically a literal), use

```
{key1 => value1, key2 => value2}
```

Rails, and other Ruby code, often pass hashes as parameters to methods to achieve the same effect as named arguments in other languages like Python.

```
object.method({:param1 => value1, :param2 => value2})
```

EDIT:  When reading, I use "gets" as the verb, eg. param1 gets value1, etc.

Comment: i like the bit about named arguments. thank you for clear response